# Applying blue theme on the spree site

Tags: spree

I am trying apply blue theme on my spree website but I am unable to do so, 
I have added `gem 'spree_blue_theme', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_blue_theme.git'`
in my gem file and bundle installed it, but then also the theme is not being applied,and the view is a bit compressed.

I have also tried it with the following code

```
gem 'spree_blue_theme', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_blue_sass_theme.git'
```

I am using rails 3.1.1 version with spree 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing, you need to run:

```
$ rake assets:clean
```

And optionally for performance:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, running `rake assets:clean` didn't seem to make any difference for me.

I had to add a line to my `app/assets/stylesheets/store/all.css` manifest file (as mentioned in this [pull request](https://github.com/spree/spree_blue_sass_theme/pull/4)):

```
*= require store/screen
```

(Actually, in the pull request it is this:

```
*= require store/spree_blue_theme
```

)